# NSFetchResultsController nil relationship section

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have a Core Data model with entities that I'm calling 'Items', which have a to one relationship with entities called 'Products'. I want to present a list of 'Items' in a table using a fetch results controller, which is not a problem.

Where I'm getting stuck is that I want all of the 'Items' that have a nil 'Product' to be in one section of the table and all the 'Items' with a product to be in another.

Can someone tell me how to setup my sort descriptors and section header key path to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do what you want without some additional work.  `NSFetchResultsController` allows you to set a field name with which to create sections, but that's going to wind up with one section for the empty products and then one for each different product.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be having different frc's for different sections. Have a common method fetchRequestForSection to which you can pass the desired section and get the custom fetch request and also make the necessary adjustments for handling section dependant info in cellForRowAtIndexPath and other tableView delegate methods.